# parallel #8 or #10 from splice point in outdoor box for 60 amp rating?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I need to repair a splice inside an outdoor, 60 amp, NEMA 3R AC cutoff switch.   The electrician had used a NSI Tork IT-4 to lengthen the #6 to reach the switch terminals (all within the box).  Its on a 60 amp breaker.

As I don't have #6 or better wire, I liked to run a pair of #8 THWN or #10 solid splice point to the switch terminal (all within the box).  Is this an acceptable practice?

The new splice would be a Morris 90612 or SR-2 splice/reducer and would be insulated with shrink tube and electrical tape - with #6 entering one side, and a pair of #10 or #8, possibly twisted, leaving the other.

Comment: Where in the world are you?  At least in the US under NEC, paralleling wires like this is not permitted, and using a non-watertight enclosure outside is also not allowed.

Comment: @NateStrickland -- there's a difference between "rainproof" (NEMA 3R, aka a typical outdoor box) and something that's actually *watertight* such as a NEMA 4X.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, ah true, I was assuming that OP meant it was an indoor box used outdoors, but you're right, if they just meant rainproof, outdoor rated but not watertight, then yes that's fine.

Comment: No. Get some #6 wire.  You're not allowed to parallel like that, and none of the splices or terminations are rated for that.  This is the kind of bodge job they find after [this](https://www.cnn.com/2016/08/11/us/california-valley-fire-faulty-hot-tub/index.html).

Comment: What is the amperage of the breaker protecting the circuit. If I am reading this right the 60A disconnect you are talking about is being used for as a equipment disconnect, not as a protection device. If your Breaker is less than 60A then your original circuit conductors are still protected.

Comment: Its a Nema3R enclosure.  Its a 60 amp cutoff switch, with a 60 amp breaker in the main panel and #6 wire.

Comment: @Harper - i'm attempting to repair the work installed and inspected by professionals - wanting to do it right, without spending a lot more $$$.  

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPYqG.jpg

Comment: @Harper - this wire slides as I push - pull on it - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHOf9.jpg
again - this was installed AND inspected by professionals - so lets just say everyone makes mistakes.

Comment: I hear you about parallel not allowed - maybe that is just "the law". But using our brains (at least a little), I'm confused because #6 wire has 19 strands of ~19 AWG (13.3mm^2/19 = ~0.7mm^2) in parallel.

Comment: @pathfinder the NFPA *also used their brains* when they wrote NEC.  When I first started working in electrical I found many of the regs to be stupid. As I learned more I realized they were correct at several levels based on real world problems.   For instance what happens when one of the two wires breaks, and all the current is flowing on the other wire?

Comment: @Harper good point, so its the jacket on the 19 strands that makes it behave as 1....

Comment: @pathfinder, the NEC is written such that any ONE fault alone won't cause a dangerous condition.  If you're using a single #6 wire and it breaks or pulls out of its termination, things stop working and you know to fix it.  If you paralleled two #8s as you suggest and one of them breaks, the other one overheats and catches on fire before you know anything is wrong.  The problem isn't the jacket, it's that you're creating dangerous single points of failure.

Comment: Just to make it clear paralleling is allowed but only with 1/0 or larger wire NEC 310.10.H.1, at my current home the shop someone had paralled 2 10-3 as a feeder to a sub panel , lucky for me they put it in conduit so it was easy to pull the non compliant wiring and pull in some thhn,  as for your grounding if you install 2 they need at least 6 feet between them 250.53.A.3

Comment: Does the shutoff switch have fuses in it?

Comment: I see the point about using only 2 wires, no redundancy.  But what if it was 6 strands of #14, all twisted.  Or if it was 19 strands of #18 twisted?  How would the latter be any different than #6 wire I just purchased?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - the cut off box is unfused.  This cut off box part of the project is okay.  I told the election what box to use (its a utility mandated solar cutoff) - they knew better - they wired in their box - then the inspector made them replace it - and the wires were to short.  I'm wondering if possibly these aluminum connectors they used - if they didn't use the anti-oxidant (or is that only required for Al wire?)

Comment: @pathfinder -- at this point, I'd have gone down to the big-box and gotten a short length of 6/2 NM to shuck for pigtails....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - that would take 3-4 hrs and its really cold and rainy so I'd probably get sick too.  I've got plenty pf #14 though!

Comment: @pathfinder -- I'd go with Harper's answer then as a *temporary* (until you can get to somewhere you can buy 6AWG wire or 6/2 NM) fix, then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92925/discussion-between-pathfinder-and-threephaseeel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allowed to parallel wires smaller than 1/0 AWG (NEC 310.10).  Further, paralleling requires special equipment on the supply-side, and special dual lugs on the load side.  This equipment handles certain very serious problems that can arise with paralleling.

Not least, what happens if one of the two wires breaks or has a contact problem, and all the current is flowing on the other wire?

It's maybe not so bad since since your issue here is entirely contained inside a junction box... *however, it's maybe not so hard to get some #6 wire*.

If you *must* cheat this, use a single #8 wire and declare "inside the box" to be a 90C environment, 55A@90C rounding up to 60A. That's not legal either, but it's a better argument than paralleling.  Then do replace it as soon as you can obtain some #6.

NFPA does a lot of thinking about electrical safety in writing the NEC.  Many rules *didn't* make sense when I started, but *do* make sense now that I have some experience and have thought more about *all* the reasons.  I have never found a rule that didn't make sense, both in terms of safety and finance.

An example is the "neutral on switch loops rule" -- it causes 50 cents worth of additional hardship at install time, and saves $200 of additional hardship (or a dangerous hack) when the homeowner wants to install a light switch.